# Should I use some blocking mechanisms with async access to DB

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm writing an async chatbot in Go with gorm and Postgres. Should I some blocking mechanism when using the gorm db client or I may safely avoid mutexes or etc. For example, I'm using gorm db client in different goroutines. Something like:

```
func () {

db.Update(...)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that.  From the official [`database/sql` docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) (which gorm wraps), we can see (emphasis added):

> The **returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines** and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the OpenDB function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

Comment: Though with gorm it's not so clear-cut. See [here](https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html#Method-Chain-Safety-x2F-Goroutine-Safety) and [here](https://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html). (using gorm.io's algolia search bar to look for "safe" may reveal other caveats)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the Gorm website, it states that the Gorm concurrent is safe, therefore, there is no need to block it.